# Grails hangs on command line

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I just downloaded Grails 2.0.1.
Created a new project  and then  tried adding the mysql connector as per the documentation but Grails hangs at command prompt without any message. I tried to execute in verbose and stacktrace mode but it prints nothing.

I tried cleaning and re-executing but all the grails commands are getting stuck.

They don't print anything beyond "configuring classpath" message .

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: so if you remove the mysql connector dependency - does it works fine !
Just making sure that it's the problem with mysql connector dep. and not some thing else.

Comment: @Sudhir: No .. the problem persists and it hangs on create-app command now or any other command

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cleaning .ivy cache helps

$HOME/.grails/ivy-cache

Comment: Did not work for me... setting the log level to verbose (as proposed in sikrip's answer) pointed me to the actual problem, though. (Repository did not repsond)

Comment: As it turns out (and also mentioned by others) one of the repositories was not responding. Once you wipe out the ivy-cache and have no connection to the repository you are screwed cause you can no longer use offline.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem on grails 2.0.4.

The cause was one of the repos not responding and grails waits for it to timeout.

Setting `log "verbose"` in BuildConfig.groovy helped me find which repository caused the problem.

Comment: Where does that log output go?

Comment: Never mind, found this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825983/how-to-get-more-info-on-grails-app-stuck-in-configuring-classpath-stage

Answer (score 4):

Try to add --offline to te command

Answer (score 1):

`$ grails clean --offline`
worked for me, as I was stuck on `configuring classpath` due to `unresolved dependencies`.