# How to get more info on Grails app stuck in Configuring classpath stage?

Tags: grails

I am running a Grails application and it just gets stuck in the Configuring class path stage, Is there any way to get more info on whats going on? I tried the `verboseCompile` switch to no avail.

```
grails run-app --verboseCompile  
| Configuring classpath
```

Comment: found it I set the log parameter in BuildConfig.groovy to verbose

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Look for the `BuildConfig.groovy` file here (`/AppName/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy`) and then find the `log` parameter and set it to `verbose`.

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
...
log "verbose" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
...
```

Comment: Where does that log output go?

Comment: Console unless log is redirected to some file

Comment: Figured it out -- I didn't have an error, it was just taking a really long time to repopulate my deleted Ivy cache. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you are not seeing any output after setting Log level to verbose, it is probably because your `grails.project.dependency.resolver` parameter is still set to `maven`. Set it to `ivy` and check again.

Answer (score 2):

Even if nothing's actually wrong, with a large project it can take a long time to download all your dependencies (especially if you clear your Ivy cache as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9320956/27358)).

Observe your Ivy cache directory (e.g. with `watch ls ~/.grails/ivy-cache`); if things are working correctly, you should see dependencies gradually being downloaded/installed there.

If things aren't working correctly (e.g. nothing's appearing there, or a few things appear and then the downloads seem to stop) Usman's [verbose logging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9840428/27358) is probably the way to go.